# in angular, using both ngRoute and ui.grid as dependencies makes the page go blank

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ngRoute and ui.grid as dependencies, but whenever I add ui.grid the localhost page becomes blank, it feels like ngRoute stops working whenever I add ui.grid as a second dependency, I am also using npm and lite-server for the localhost, and i made sure to install both angular route and angular ui grid.
The console log is giving me this error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
[this is the error page from angular's original site][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxiVM.png)
I have an angularJS application but I'm a beginner so I can't work around this problem, any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS:this is my first question so go easy on me if it's too vague.

Comment: Firstly check developer console for error messages. Then check that you added script tag `<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js">`. It can be that ui.grid corrupts ngRoute.

Comment: I am actually including the script, and the console gives me this error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=Error%3A…0%20%20%20at%20Sc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fangular.js%3A22%3A179)

Comment: Seems that the link to error you provided is corrupted, can you copy the full error link and paste here?

Comment: I added a an image to the question of the error page, for some reason the $ sign in the link is'nt working, if you could please check the image out and tell me if you know anything about it, thanks for you're concern :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently I was missing a couple of  tags in my code, once I linked them my code worked, sorry for the bother